# How to Disbale multimedia in WebBrowser Control in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I'm developing a program that load webpages using WebBrowser control in VB6. How do i disable loading multimedia like pictures, flash, sounds ??

If there is no way then I'd be glad if you can find a another way using registry.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser control is simply using Microsoft Internet Explorer under the covers. I would imagine if you disable multi-media from IE Tools->Options you will see the effect when using the web browser control in VB6.